# what is stack space reusage

Tags: c, gcc, stack

There is an option "-fstack-reuse" at the gcc at code generation conventions.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options

When functions return; their stack also are rewinding. But what does stack reuse option mean exactly ?

Comment: This seems to be a question about compiler implementation, not about C. Although I don't see how the phrase "These machine-independent options" in your link works with the use of a stack, since the C standard never mentions a stack (or heap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previous GCC versions were rather conservative when it came to reusing stack allocations even though the lifetimes of the objects were not overlapping.  This had the effect that a lot of broken code which referenced to out-of-scope local variables or already-destructed temporary objects worked by accident.  The `-fstack-reuse` option is there to provide some level of support for compiling such broken code (although it can probably still break due to other optimizations kicking in).

The option does *not* affect what happens when a function returns.  With or without this option, the stack frame is always destroyed, and all local objects cease to exist.  It only affects scope exit (where named variables are deallocated) and the completion of the evaluation of full expressions in C++ (where temporary objects are deallocated).

If your code avoids dangling pointers, the option is of no use to you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. previous gcc versions conservative means they did not rewind stack spaces after functions returns ?  in fact i could not understand the point between stack rewind and stack space reuse. Stack space rewinding is the default in C afaik. But that stack space reuse option for what ?

Comment: No, the function return sequence is not affected by this option. It's about scope exits within the function.

Comment: Florian your explanation is enlightening and comprehensive. i understand the point for the stack reusage for the variables with the scope concept. thanks .

Answer (score 3):

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) has a very clear example for stack reuse:

```
int *p;
{
    int local1;

    p = &local1;
    local1 = 10;
    ...
} // local1 lifetime is over, but p still points to local1
{
    int local2;
    local2 = 20;
    ...
} // local2 might reuse local1 space

if (*p == 10)  // out of scope use of local1
{
    ...
}
```

So, the option basically means if each local variable has a dedicated stack space. If option is used (default), local variables with non-overlapping lifetimes might use the same stack space (as variables `local1` and `local2` in the example above.

It is just for the local variables and temporaries, it has nothing to do with stack clean-up.

The stack clean-up is happening always after return and regardless of the `-fstack-reuse` option. But due to the option, we might need to allocate (and clean-up after return) more space on stack for the same number of local variables.

Comment: thanks Andriy  i got the idea of scope and reuse of stack for automatic variables